# magento model file not found / incorrectly included

Tags: php, magento, autoloader

I'm trying to add a module (it's called paypal-payment fee) to our magento shop, but as soon as its installed it produces an error on every shop site.

```
Warning: include(FlyWebdesign_PaypalFee_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Paymentcharge.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
```

it seems that the autoloader is trying to include the file with underscores instead of slashes, but in the Documentation it says that the underscores are replaced with slashes automatically by the autoloader, so i don't understand what is causing the error.

Thanks in advance

Samuel

Comment: Please post your file/directory hierarchy to check the file path is correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shop probably has compilation enabled. When you install a  new module  the code has to be re-compiled, otherwise this kind of error happens.

Try to disable the compilation, re-install your module and enable the compilation again.